# $\int_{-1}^{1}|f(t)|dt \geq C\left(\int_{0}^{2}|f(t)|^2\right)^{1/2}$ for polynomials

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, alternative-proof

> Prove that there exists constant $C>0$ that for all $f \in P_n$ we have:
>   $$\int_{-1}^{1}|f(t)|dt \geq C\left(\int_{0}^{2}|f(t)|^2\right)^{1/2}$$
>   Where $P_n$ is space of polynomials with degree less than or equal to $n$.

There is one solution using functional analysis: first we note that functions $\|\|_1$ and $\|\|_2$ are norms on $P_n$:

$$\|f\|_1=\int_{-1}^{1}|f(t)|dt$$

$$\|f\|_2=\left(\int_{0}^{2}|f(t)|^2\right)^{1/2}$$

Now $P_n$ is finite vector space and all norms on finite vector spaces are equivalent, so the inequality holds.

In my opinions it's a suprising result, so I'm looking for elementary proof of this inequality.

Comment: $0$ works... :)

Comment: Note that you can't use the equivalence of norms because you are working on different intervals. Or, is it a typo?

Comment: No, it's not typo. Note that in general is shouldn't be norms, but for polynomial is (problem in general is that $\|f\|_1=0$ doesn't imply $f=0$, but it's not a problem for polynomials). @user2345215 thank, i corrected $C>0$.

Comment: I think they are both norms on the same finite-dimensional vector space, regardless of the fact that the integrals are over different intervals. So the OP's argument looks solid to me. ($C$ needs to depend on $n$, of course.)

Comment: In principal, you could write $f(t)$ as a linear combination of $f(t-2)$, $f(t-1-\frac{n-1}n)$, ..., $f(t-1-\frac1n)$, $f(t-1)$ (because finite-dimensional vector space). That would at least allow the integral $\int_1^2 f(t)^2\,dt$ to be written in terms of the values of $f$ between $-1$ and $1$....

Comment: What do you mean by an elementary proof? One where you will use inequalities and get a value for $C$?

Because to just prove the existence you could mimic the prove that all norms are equivalent on finite dimensional spaces without using the theorem itself.

Comment: Yes, of course proof that all norms are equivalent on finite dimensional spaces and using this can be understood aselementary proof. But I'm looking for more natural proof (without using norms and finite vector spaces) maybe with getting value of $C$ but not necessary.

Comment: I really like this question. I've been bothered trying to think of a constructive proof--one where I can get a number for $C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the contrary, that for every $k$ there exists a non zero polynomial $p_k$ of degree $n$ such that 
$$ \int_{-1}^1 |p_k(t)|dt \leq \frac{1}{k} \left( \int_0^2 |p_k(t)|^2dt \right)^{1/2}$$
We can assume that $\int_0^2|p_k|^2=1$, because the inequality is scale invariant. This means that $\int_{-1}^1 |p_k(t)|dt \leq \frac{1}{k}$ so $p_k \to 0$ in $L^1([-1,1])$. We can extract a subsequence such that $p_k \to 0$ almost everywhere. We note by $N$ the negligible set where the convergence does not take place.

Choose $n+1$ distinct points $x_1,...,x_{n+1}$ in $[0,1]\setminus N$. Then $p_k(x_i)$ is convergent to $0$ for $i=1..n+1$. If we do a Lagrange interpolation procedure for each $p_k$ with the values at the points $x_1,...,x_{n+1}$, we see that all coefficients in the Lagrange basis go to $0$.

Thus $p_k$ converges uniformly to $p=0$ on compact intervals. But this contradicts $\int_0^2|p_k|^2=1$

---

This is not really elementary. It would be if you could get rid of the part that the convergence in $L^1$ implies convergence almost everywhere of a subsequence.

Comment: Nice proof, it's similar to proof that all norms are equivalent on finite dimensional spaces, but without using this explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

I can show the claim when the interval is the same for each integral, let's say it is $[-1,1]$, and if there is a restriction on the roots of $f(t)$. I thought about this for a while and figured I might as well post it. I'm slightly hopeful with some more thinking a full solution will come.

First, suppose $f(t)=\prod (t-\alpha_i)$ with $|\alpha_i| > 3$. We will prove a helpful inequality. For $|x|<1$, $|t|<1$, $|\alpha|>3$, we have
$$ \frac{|t-\alpha|}{|x-\alpha|} \geq \frac{||t|-|\alpha||}{|x|+|\alpha|} \geq \frac{|\alpha|-1}{|\alpha|+1} = 1 - \frac{2}{|\alpha|+1} \geq \frac{1}{2} $$
This means $\sup_{|x|<1} |x-\alpha_i| \leq 2 |t-\alpha_i|$ for all $|t|<1$ and hence

$$\prod_{i=1}^n \sup_{|x|<1} |x-\alpha_i| \leq 2^n |f(t)| \quad \mbox{ or } \quad \prod_{i=1}^n \sup_{|x|<1} |x-\alpha_i| \leq 2^{n+1} \int_{-1}^1 |f(t)| dt.$$

Second, we write 
$$\int_{-1}^1 f(t)^2 dt = \int_{-1}^1 \prod (t-\alpha_i)^2 dt \leq \left( \prod_{i=1}^n \sup_{x \in [-1,1]} ||x-\alpha_i|| \right) \int_{-1}^1 \prod |t-\alpha_i|dt$$

Because $2xy \leq x^2 +y^2$ we can write

$$2 \int_{-1}^1 f(t)^2 dt \leq \left( \prod_{i=1}^n \sup_{x \in [-1,1]} ||x-\alpha_i|| \right)^2 + \left( \int_{-1}^1 \prod |t-\alpha_i|dt \right)^2.$$

Finally, we use one of the inequalities we proved earlier to write

$$\frac{2}{1+2^{n+1}}\int_{-1}^1 f(t)^2 dt  \leq  \left( \int_{-1}^1 |f(t)|dt \right)^2.$$

Comment: I'm pretty I can extend this proof to exclude only roots in $A \subset [-1,1]$ for any $A^c$ with $dist(A^c, [-1,1]) = \epsilon > 0$. The problem is that $C \approx \epsilon^{-n}$. One of those classic annoying tradeoffs in analysis.